# Cache Memory 4 Way Set Associative

Tags: caching, memory

Suppose you have a 4-way set associative cache. The main memory is 1 KB which has address lenght = 10 bit. The cache memory consist 4 words ( 1 word = 1 bit )for each lines. And the tag is 5 bit. How can i find the size of the cache memory ?